# Instant Run performed a full build and install Warning

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

I got below warning on new version of Android studio. When I search for it, I didnt find any solution. This warning appears after installing new version. I am waiting your helps.

"***Instant Run performed a full build and install since the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk***"

Comment: go ahead. don't worry.

Comment: the instant run version might be changed so it is trying to "full build" the apk for compatibility.

Comment: But no longer, apk of app is been installing slowly as regards old version

Comment: I have the same message..is this an error or a problem?